# In React Native, is grouping all the images in one object bad for performance?

Tags: performance, react-native, require

I have a file with a long list of images like this

```
const images = {
  cities: {
    amsterdam: require('../assets/images/amsterdam.jpg'),
    ashford: require('../assets/images/ashford.jpg'),
    avignon: require('../assets/images/avignon.jpg'),
    brussels: require('../assets/images/brussels.jpg'),
    ...
  },
};

export default images;
```

Then I import one in my component like this

```
import images from './images';

const MyComp = () => (<Image source={images.city.amsterdam} />);
```

I was wondering how React Native will handle the `require` and if it would affect the performance in the app?

Would it be more performant to use something like this?:

```
const amsterdam = require('../assets/images/amsterdam.jpg')
const MyComp = () => (<Image source={amsterdam} />);
```

Answer (score 0):

I  would recommend to load the images if needed (if you have much images like you told), instead of loading (means requiring) all images at loading-time of the Component.

For that keep an Array or Object with the filenames (and path).
If you use flatlist to manage your images, it do the job most of the job (loading right image at right time) for you, because you can configure flatlist how many items (additional to the current one you see in the screen) will be loaded.

Then create a component which load the needed image - and for best results keep still loaded images in cache.

I got good results with this strategy. You also could give `react-native-image-zoom-viewer` or `react-native-fast-image` a chance.